# Alt combination doesn't work well Blender 2.78 and 2.79, Windows 7 x64

Tags: shortcut, windows

I discovered that <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> doesn't work and I was unable to unhide objects.
After a series of tests and looking online, I discovered myself that the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> key doesn't work always, but the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> (<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>) does.

In User Preferences, if I try to edit certain commands that had already <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>some key</kbd>, I press the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> and it appears in the box waiting for the other key, but if I press the key it doesn't catch it. But if I try with <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> and then I press the key, it works.

For sure it does not take <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>.

Blender 2.78 and 2.79, Windows 7 x64, US International Keyboard.

It's not an hardware issue because I also tried with the on-screen keyboard.

Comment: I'm not a Windows user, so I can't say this for certain, but could it be that Windows maps the non-functioning shortcuts to something?

Comment: I had the same problem, eventually realized that the shortcut was shared with another software I use (Simple Sticky Notes), I closed that and it started working normally

Comment: @stan I will try to check if Sticky Notes is active, and try to kill it. Duane,  maybe is like Stan said.

Comment: Sir i also face the problem with Alt + A/S/D/R. I try everything that on internet but still the issue is not solve. Please help me.